# Define a function to create a new dictionary from one string

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary

I have the following PDB format code about one hypotethical new chemical substance called "new_mol":

```
new_mol= """
ATOM     45  C  BARG A  -3      12.759  86.530  96.365  0.50 36.39     C
ATOM     46  O  BARG A  -3      12.924  87.757  96.420  0.50 37.26     O
ATOM     47  CB BARG A  -3      13.428  85.746  93.980  0.50 36.60     C
ATOM     48  CG BARG A  -3      12.866  85.172  92.651  0.50 37.31     C
ATOM     49  CD BARG A  -3      13.374  85.886  91.406  0.50 37.66     C
ATOM     50  NE BARG A  -3      12.644  85.487  90.195  0.50 38.24     N
ATOM     51  CZ BARG A  -3      13.114  85.582  88.947  0.50 39.55     C
ATOM     52  NH1BARG A  -3      14.338  86.056  88.706  0.50 40.23     N

"""
import os
```

where the last letter of each line is the atom symbol.

I would like to define a function

```
def count_atom(new_mol):
num_atoms = dict()
```

that creates a dictionary in order to obtain a result as:

```
#num_atoms = {'C':5, 'O':1; 'N':2}
```

Therefore I would like to create in Python a dictionary which displays the total number of each atom of the new_mol variable.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome. You haven't forgotten to ask a precise question (or actually, any question at all) - we can't write your code for you, so it'd be better if you tried, and then showed what you've tried, why it didn't work and ask the question you need to ask to solve your problem.

Comment: The input string looks like a file. If you get it from a file, just process the file line by line counting occurences of last non space character, and if it is really a string, use the `io` module to process it like a file object: `io.BytesIO` in Python 2 or `io.StringIO` in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, you can use it according to your requirement. desired result is in result_dict varriable

```
new_mol= """
ATOM     45  C  BARG A  -3      12.759  86.530  96.365  0.50 36.39     C
ATOM     46  O  BARG A  -3      12.924  87.757  96.420  0.50 37.26     O
ATOM     47  CB BARG A  -3      13.428  85.746  93.980  0.50 36.60     C
ATOM     48  CG BARG A  -3      12.866  85.172  92.651  0.50 37.31     C
ATOM     49  CD BARG A  -3      13.374  85.886  91.406  0.50 37.66     C
ATOM     50  NE BARG A  -3      12.644  85.487  90.195  0.50 38.24     N
ATOM     51  CZ BARG A  -3      13.114  85.582  88.947  0.50 39.55     C
ATOM     52  NH1BARG A  -3      14.338  86.056  88.706  0.50 40.23     N

"""
list_of_string = new_mol.split('ATOM')
result_dict = {}
for string in list_of_string:
    chamical_info = string.strip()
    if chamical_info:
        print chamical_info[-1]
        if result_dict.has_key(chamical_info[-1]):
            result_dict[chamical_info[-1]] = result_dict[chamical_info[-1]] + 1
        else:
            result_dict[chamical_info[-1]] = 1


print result_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a class Counter in module collections that does exatly that. When you hava a list of the atoms you just have to create a Counter with `Counter(atoms)` and you have the desired result.

```
from collections import Counter

new_mol= """
ATOM     45  C  BARG A  -3      12.759  86.530  96.365  0.50 36.39     C
ATOM     46  O  BARG A  -3      12.924  87.757  96.420  0.50 37.26     O
ATOM     47  CB BARG A  -3      13.428  85.746  93.980  0.50 36.60     C
ATOM     48  CG BARG A  -3      12.866  85.172  92.651  0.50 37.31     C
ATOM     49  CD BARG A  -3      13.374  85.886  91.406  0.50 37.66     C
ATOM     50  NE BARG A  -3      12.644  85.487  90.195  0.50 38.24     N
ATOM     51  CZ BARG A  -3      13.114  85.582  88.947  0.50 39.55     C
ATOM     52  NH1BARG A  -3      14.338  86.056  88.706  0.50 40.23     N
"""

atoms = [line.split()[-1] for line in new_mol.splitlines() if line.startswith('ATOM')]
atom_count = Counter(atoms)
```